# rails sanitize method not removing html tags

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-5, sanitize

I have a string with some html code inside:

```
html_var = <h2>hello world</h2><p>foo bar</p> <b>and something else until 400 characters...</b>
```

And I need the first 180 characters without the html tags.

I used `truncate(html_var, :length => 180)` and it works fine for the 180 characters.

And I found http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html to clean all the html tags. So I tried `truncate(sanitize(html_var), :length => 180)` and it returns to me

```
<h2>hello world</h2><p>foo bar</p> <b>and truncated to 180 chars
```

I tried also with `strip_tags` but still the same result, at least is the result I see in the share screen of facebook. As I am using this variable in the og:description meta.

Answer (score 3):

seems like sanitize allow some default tags if not specified explicitly
reference: https://github.com/rails/rails-html-sanitizer/blob/master/lib/rails/html/sanitizer.rb

try using sanitize(str, {:tags => []})

Answer (score 1):

i know its late. but may be this answer will help other user
 You can remove html tags by using strip_tags.

Use this code

```
html_var = <h2>hello world</h2><p>foo bar</p> <b>and something else until 400 characters...</b>
strip_tags(html_var.html_safe)
```

Hope it will help you in future.

Comment: Thank you, it is not late yet, but I tried with strip_tags and same result. When it is twitter description works fine, but with the facebook description all the tags remain there.